# How to cause workstations on network to install msi package?

Tags: deployment, windows-sbs-2008, msi

I have remote access to a `Windows Small Business Server 2008` machine.  There are about 5 workstations connected to this network.

How can I make every workstation install an `.msi` package without having to remotely connect to each workstation?

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply considered using your active Directory to publish the application via a Group Policy?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

explains how to do it (and no, I will not Quote a 2 page Long checklist of steps to do).

Comment: Can this method cause the application to be published to all workstations on a per-machine basis and does this require a domain?

Comment: Domain. Pretty much all higher admin functions in windows and for windows are made for domains.

Answer (score 0):

PsExec... erk.  OK for v-small environments, but doesn't scale into the enterprise.  Seen plenty of bombed PSExec child processes / residual PSExecSvc services.

If AD based deployment isn't an option, and the clients are Win7/8, use WinRM.

Answer (score -2):

You have three options:

1. [Windows logon script](http://computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/logon_scripts.htm)
2. [Miscrosoft Systems Management Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978225.aspx)
3. [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

But i recommend you to use psexec, because its so easy and stable.it has working for me about 3 years without any problem. the main role of psexec is to execute a command remotely on another computer, even the executable does not exists on remote computer.it may copy executable on remote computer and then executes it.

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file][-u user [-p psswd]][-n s][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,... ] cmd [arguments]
```

**EDIT 1:**

On unix based workstations, you may use [WINEXE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) instead.

Comment: -1. THere are 4 optiosn. Nr 4 is simply Publishing it in the Group policy as published application.

Comment: With `psexec` do you have to know the username/password of the remote computer?

Comment: Does your option 2 require there to be a Active Directory domain?

Comment: SMS was rebranded to SCCM over a decade ago.